# MongoDB: determining if there are any objects with a specific count for a particular sub-array value

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Essentially, I have:

- a `bands` collection
- each band *may or may not* have an array of `players`
- each player has an array of `roles` (string)

E.g.:

```
// a band
{
  _id: 1,
  players: [
    { 
      name: "George",
      roles: [ "GUITAR" ]
    },
    { 
      name: "John",
      roles: [ "SINGER", "GUITAR" ]
    },
    { 
      name: "Paul",
      roles: [ "SINGER", "BASS GUITAR" ]
    },
    { 
      name: "Ringo",
      roles: [ "DRUMS" ]
    },
  ]
}
```

I need to determine if there is *any* band which contains *more than one* member having the *SINGER* role.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative to the `$unwind / $group` solution would be [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "players.roles": "GUITAR"
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "member_cnt": {
        $size: {
          $filter: {
            input: "$players",
            cond: {
              $in: [
                "GUITAR",
                "$$this.roles"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "member_cnt": {
        $gt: 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      member_cnt: 0
    }
  }
])
```

It should be a bit faster as it doesn't have blocking $group stage.

Comment: This runs much faster than the solution I posted, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Some easy option:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
 {
   $unwind: "$players"
  },
 {
   $unwind: "$players.roles"
 },
 {
   $match: {
     "players.roles": "SINGER"
  }
  },
   {
   $group: {
    _id: "$_id",
    cnt: {
    $sum: 1
    }
   }
  },
  {
    $match: {
     cnt: {
      $gt: 1
      }
    }
  }
 ])
```

explained:

1. unwind 1st array
2. unwind 2nd array
3. Filter only the roles SINGER
4. group by band _id and count the SINGER roles.
5. Filter only the bands with >1 SINGER

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/vfpjhSpX5gd)

Comment: I wouldn't double unwind whole collection. Add a copy of $match as a first stage to unwind only documents that has at least 1 singer.

Comment: I have assumed there is always at least one singer in the band :) , but indeed the filter solution seems to perform better  ...

Comment: I really liked the output of this option as "{ _id: ..., cnt: ...}", though it seems to be too heavy for a larger collection: "MongoServerError: Exceeded memory limit for $group, but didn't allow external sort. Pass allowDiskUse:true to opt in."

Answer (score 1):

This query seems to give me what I need:

```
db.bands.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      players: {
        $ifNull: [
          "$players",
          []
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "$expr": {
        "$gt": [
          {
            "$size": {
              "$filter": {
                "input": "$players",
                "as": "player",
                "cond": {
                  "$in": [
                    "SINGER",
                    "$$player.roles"
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          },
          1
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: wow , beauty ,  thanks for sharing !